# Java URLConnection to php

Tags: java, php, urlconnection

How to write this code in php?

What i should use? CURL? fsockopen ? and what is actually send to server (outputString is a post / get and what its variable name)?

```
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
out.write(outputString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.close();

conn.connect();

final int code = conn.getResponseCode();
final String contentType = conn.getContentType();
final StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");

char[] msg = new char[2048];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(msg)) > 0) {
    responseText.append(msg, 0, len);
}
```

Thank you for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic example of a cURL post...

Further reading at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php has very good examples too.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.site.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3");

// Get server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($result == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

An example for SENDING XML:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Define POST URL and also payload
     */
    define('XML_PAYLOAD', '<?xml version="1.0"?><member><name>name</name></member>');
    define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://www.domain.com/build_xml.php');

    /**
     * Initialize handle and set options
     */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));

    /**
     * Execute the request and also time the transaction
     */
    $start = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $stop = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    $totalTime = $stop - $start;

    /**
     * Check for errors
     */
    if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
        $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        switch($returnCode){
            case 404:
                $result = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the handle
     */
    curl_close($ch);

    /**
     * Output the results and time
     */
    echo 'Total time for request: ' . $totalTime . "\n";
    echo $result;  

    /**
     * Exit the script
     */
    exit(0);
?>
```

And a 3rd for good measure, just to illustrate an alternative approach;

```
<?php
$xml     = '<request>Testing</request>';
$server  = '...'; // URL to server.php
$options = array 
(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $server,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $xml,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($response), '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Hi brian thanks for answer, on my above code is actually send serialized outputString. but i don't know what is send, i try to debug in my php server and i got nothing, but in java server it proceed successfully. unfortunately i cannot open  the java server code.

Comment: OK in your example above it looks like it's sending XML. Have updated with example I refer to for myself.

Comment: thanks brian, i don't know if we can send post request with out any name on it. thanks.